What are the requirements for the messiah?
I am considering becoming an Orthodox Jew but I was born and raised a Christian, I know little much about the Jewish faith but I want to learn, my question being what is the requirements that they are the messiah and why did Jesus not fufill these?

Read the top answer of the duplicate question. It's got 90+ upvotes for a reason , it will answer your question
